# variable decl in js

Tags: javascript

```
function antalAr(lan, amortering)
        {
               totalAmorteringAr = amortering * 12;
               for( var svar = 0; totalAmorteringAr * svar <= lan; svar++){}
               return svar;
        }

        var tal1 = antalAr(1000000,1000);
        document.writeln("Ett lån på 1000000 kr är betalt efter " + Math.ceil(tal1) + " år om amorteringen är 1000 kr/mån.");

        var tal2 = antalAr(1500000,500);
        document.writeln("Ett lån på 1500000 kr är betalt efter " + Math.ceil(tal2) + " år om amorteringen är 500 kr/mån.");
```

*The right answer it should print out:*

**Ett lån på 1000000 kr är betalt efter 84 år om amorteringen är 1000 kr/mån. 
Ett lån på 1500000 kr är betalt efter 250 år om amorteringen är 500 kr/mån**.

But it keeps add plus one year: *Ett lån på 1500000 kr är betalt efter **251** år om amorteringen är 500 kr/mån*

**Why?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite difficult to debug code in a foreign language, but it seems to me that you're incrementing one too many times:

```
for( var svar = 0; totalAmorteringAr * svar <= lan; svar++){}
```

If you change the `<=` to `<`, your code should work.

Comment: Dangit, I was having the same debugging difficulties and just saw that too! Well, +1 for you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Math.ceil should be Math.floor.

ceil round up, not down, which means it will "finish" the year.

Comment: Those values will always be integers (they are set to `0` and then incremented with `++`), so that can't be the issue. `Math.ceil(4)` returns `4`.

Comment: I have do use math.ceil in this assigment